# Excel spawned from powershell script not quitting

Tags: excel, powershell, com

We're migrating databases so I'm using powershell to modify the hundreds of excel files that reference to old DB instance to the new one. This is all fine and works as intended. The problem I have is that the Excel application will not exit when I'm done. The process will just hang around as a background process and I need to go into task manager to kill it. Not a huge deal but it is annoying. Here is my script. I'm on powershell v5 and Office 2016.

```
    param(
    [string]$search_root=$(throw "missing search root parameter"),
    [boolean]$test=$true
)
echo $search_root

$NAMEPOSTFIX = '-Updated'
$OLDCONN = 'Data Source=abc;'
$NEWCONN = 'Data Source=xyz;'

$filelist = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_root *.xls* -Recurse -Exclude '*Updated.*'
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

function update_con_xls{
    param($file)    
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
    foreach($con in $Workbook.Connections){
        if ($con.OLEDBConnection -ne $null){
            $con.OLEDBConnection.Connection = $con.OLEDBConnection.Connection.Replace($OLDCONN,$NEWCONN)
        }
        if ($con.ODBCConnection -ne $null){
            $con.ODBCConnection.Connection = $con.ODBCConnection.Connection.Replace($OLDCONN,$NEWCONN)
        }
    }
    $Workbook.Save()
    $Workbook.saved = $true
    $Excel.Workbooks.Close()
}

foreach ($file in $filelist) {
    echo $file
    if ($file.Extension -eq '.xls' -or $file.Extension -eq '.xlsx') {
        $newfile = ($file.DirectoryName + '\' + $file.BaseName + $NAMEPOSTFIX + $file.Extension)
        if($test){
            echo $test
            $newfile = ('C:\test\' + $file.Name) #for test run to copy coppy locally 
        }
        Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $newfile
        update_con_xls($newfile)
    }
}
$Excel.Quit()
$Excel = $null
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798567/powershell-excel-save-and-close-after-run/35955339#35955339

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change:

```
$Excel.Workbooks.Close()
```

to :

```
$Excel= New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($file);
$Workbook.Save();
$Workbook.Close(); # <--- try

$Excel.Quit();
Remove-Variable -Name Excel;
```

I do not see anything here that could close your ODB and OLEDb connection trying to add:

```
$con.OLEDBConnection.Connection.Close();
$con.ODBCConnection.Connection.Close();
```

or

```
$con.OLEDBConnection.Close();
$con.ODBCConnection.Close();
```

after your work is finished.

Comment: No that didn't change anything. Also the connections are never opened. I'm just changing the property of what it points to. I can even create the $Excel object then immediately close and remove the variable  and it still stays in running memory.

Comment: ok, try $workbook.SaveAs($outputfile); , because Save() function probably block ?

Comment: this work for me:          $workbook.SaveAs($outputfile);
         $workbook.Close();
         $excel.Quit();
         Remove-Variable -Name excel;

Comment: Also , have you try to put : $Excel.Visible  = $false;

Comment: From here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798567/powershell-excel-save-and-close-after-run:

The documentation recommends using FinalReleaseComObject method to completely release the COM object and close the Excel process once in for all.