# Unable to run this script for second time

Tags: powershell

I am saving OGN.xlsx file as jeeva.csv. The below code runs for the first time and creates jeeva.csv.

```
PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open('D:\OGN.xlsx')
PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $workbook.SaveAs('D:\jeeva.csv',6)
```

File jeeva.csv created

When i run the same again:

```
PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open('D:\OGNPL300.xlsx')
PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $workbook.SaveAs('D:\jeeva.csv',6)
```

I get this error:

Exception calling "SaveAs" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot access 'jeeva.csv'."
At line:1 char:1
+ $workbook.SaveAs('D:\jeeva.csv',6)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Comment: Editing the second command in rerun , this is what run PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open('D:\OGN.xlsx')

Comment: Just because you saved the workbook it does not mean you closed it.

Comment: How to close that file?

Comment: I did this $workbook.Close() still same

Comment: Excel is fun like that. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798567/powershell-excel-save-and-close-after-run

Comment: PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $workbook.Close($false)
PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $excel.Quit()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $excel.Quit()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $Excel.Quit()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Excel.Quit()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: $excel.Quit() and $Excel.Quit() didnt work, tried this $Excel.Quit executed ok.but re ran the three commands again and same error

Comment: You do not have a variable called `$excel` in your sample code above you called it `$objExcel`...

Comment: PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $objExcel.Quit

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Quit()
void _Application.Quit()
PS C:\Users\Jeevananda_R> $objExcel.Quit() ran and same again

Comment: Please stop putting errors and code in comments. Edit your question with all the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.displayAlerts = $false
$workbook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open('C:\test\test.xlsx')
$workbook.SaveAs('c:\test\new.csv',6) 
$workbook.close
[void]$objExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: Can you rerun the same first three commands again, because i copy pasted you code getting same error , work for first run but for the second time faile with same error

Comment: I dont get any errors if running the above in either the console or the ISE

Comment: Windows powershell , in windows search i did a search for powershell and promt came up. Win 8.1 32 bit

Comment: Try ending all of your excel prossess first then try the code I posted again (edit the file paths )

Comment: I also suggest to release the Excel com object after quitting Excel: `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel) | Out-Null ;
[System.GC]::Collect() ;
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: The answer does not show you using the com object to save _another_ file using the same output name.

Comment: Matt, if you comment out line 2 of my code you will be prompted to overwrite the file the second time you run it.

Comment: @Theo Don't forget to collect the `$workbook` object as well.