# Trim a excel cell with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, com

Is it possible to trim a excel cell like this:

```
<newline>
<newline>
A
B
C
<newline>
<newline>
```

to:

```
A
B
C
```

I tried it with the COM Object:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path)
foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets){
[void]$ws.Cells.Trim()
}
```

But `Trim()` is not a valid method. Is there any other way to Trim excel cell(s) for a complete worksheet or a given range `($ws.Range)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netcore-3.1) is a method on `System.String`. You must use it on a cell's value, not the cell itself, and then update the changed value. I used [UsedRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange) but you can change it to any other range:

```bsh
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($path)
foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets){
    foreach ($cell in $ws.UsedRange) {
        if ($cell.Value2 -ne $null) {
            $cell.Value2 = $cell.Value2.Trim()
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798567/excel-save-and-close-after-run) or cleanup the Excel object after.